# jQuery ajax request done only works in chrome and not the other browsers

Tags: jquery

i have the below code to alert users when the report is being successfully emailed to them. However i notice the alert is only shown in chrome and not the other browsers. I can't figure out what is wrong. Pls help me. Thank You.

```
 $("#rpt_email").click(function(event) {
 var ajaxRequest;

 /* Stop form from submitting normally */
 event.preventDefault();

 /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */   
   ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
        url: "emailReport.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { 'summary_ttl_value': "5.55%"}            
    });

  ajaxRequest.done(function (){     
      alert("The report has been sent to your email");         
 });  


 ajaxRequest.fail(function (){          
  alert("The report could not be sent");
 });

});
```

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: Could be cache issue, no?! And what about error in e.g FF console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a success function inside the request instead of ".done" after the fact.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "emailReport.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { 'summary_ttl_value': "5.55%"},
        success: function(response) { 
            getUserPreference(response);
           }
       });
```

Alternatively, I noticed your .done function is contained within the click handler.  Try moving it outside that function, just like you did with the .fail function.  It could be that it only works on Chrome because Chrome is a faster browser and was able to get to the .done code before the click event/ajax request was processed.

Comment: Because success is more widely accepted, and if I remember correctly, .done wasn't implemented until JQuery 1.5

Comment: That's why I asked him what version he was using.

Comment: This works, Thank you. But why doesn't my solution work?

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: i see, its version issue. my version is 1.11.3

Comment: @Dev `done()` was added in jq 1.5 and 1.11 > 1.5... So that was not your issue

Comment: Regarding your update, that's not how it works. The done() callback would still be fired

Comment: @A.Wolff since you seem to have all the answers, please feel free to tell us why his original code doesn't work then.

Comment: I not have 'all the answers' but i'm sure your answer has nothing to do with OP's issue. It just sounds like browser cache issue. Now if OP reuse its original code, he'll just see it works as expected

Comment: Well hopefully they try that and post back the results here because I'd be curious to know how that happened.

Comment: @Ageonix I'm curious too.